# How can I get the number of groups to vary depending on the number of lines?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, split

I have this regex: `^:([^:]+):([^:]*)` which works as in [this regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/qM5nR0/2).

Now, in Python, I have this:

```
def get_data():
    data = read_mt_file()
    match_fields = re.compile('^:([^:]+):([^:]*)', re.MULTILINE)

    fields = re.findall(match_fields, data)

    return fields
```

Which, for a file containing the data from regex101, returns:

```
[('1', 'text\ntext\n\n'), ('20', 'text\n\n'), ('21', 'text\ntext\ntext\n\n'), ('22', ' \n\n'), ('25', 'aa\naa\naaaaa')]
```

Now, this is ok, but I want to change the regex, so that I can get the number of groups to vary depending on the number of lines. Meaning:

- for the first line, now, I get two groups:

  1. `1`
  2. `text\ntext\n\n`

I'd like to get instead:

1. `1`
2. ((`text\n`), (`text\n\n`)) <-- those should be somehow in the same group but separated, each in his own *subgroup*. Somehow I need to know they both belong to `1` field, but are sepparate lines.

So, In python, the desired result for that file would be:

```
[('1', '(text\n), (text\n\n)'), ('20', 'text\n\n'), ('21', '(text\n), (text\n), (text\n\n)'), ('22', ' \n\n'), ('25', '(aa\n), (aa\n), (aaaaa)')]
```

Is this possible with regex? Could this be achieved with some nice string manipulation instead ?

Comment: You can't have a regex return a variable number of groups. You could do something like `((\w*)(?:\s(\w+))?)` to split the text into groups 3 and 4, but a better solution would be to use the regex you have and then split the contents of group 2 with something like `(?<=\n)(?=\w)`.

Comment: With `re` regex, you may get the chunks, but then you need to perform additional manipulations with the results. With PyPi regex module, you can get that with 1 regex operation by accessing repeated captures.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it doesn't matter if I'll have to perform other additional manipulation with the results as far as they will be closer to what I need :P

Comment: What about `[[x.group(1), re.findall(r".+\n*", x.group(2))] for x in re.finditer(match_fields, data)]`?

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/hO7SyM - maybe this is what you need? The result is a list of lists - `[['1', 'text\n', 'text\n\n'], ['20', 'text\n\n'], ['21', 'text\n', 'text\n', 'text\n\n'], ['22', ' \n\n'], ['25', 'aa\n', 'aa\n', 'aaaaa']]`

Comment: Or `print([(x, "({})".format(re.sub(r".+(?!\n*$)\n+", r"\g<0>), (", y))) for x, y in p.findall(s)])` - https://ideone.com/DPP9mq

Comment: Thanks a lot. That last one gave me a serious brain damage

Comment: Please add `@`+username when you comment, I was not aware of your latest comment. Should I post these 2? Did either of them answer your question? I could post (and when I post, I explain the code, without risking your brain :))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sure!

Comment: Ok, once I'm at home I will post both with explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want, you'd need another regex.
This is as `re.match` only matches the last item it matches:

```
>>> re.match(r'(\d)+', '12345').groups()
('5',)
```

Instead of using one regex you'll need to use two.
The one that you are using at the moment, and then one to match all the 'sub-groups', using say `re.findall`.
You can get these sub-groups by simply matching anything that isn't a `\n` and then any amount of `\n`.

So you could use a regex such as `[^\n]+\n*`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[^\n]+\n*', 'text\ntext')
['text\n', 'text']
>>> re.findall(r'[^\n]+\n*', 'text\ntext\n\n')
['text\n', 'text\n\n']
>>> re.findall(r'[^\n]+\n*', '')
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a simple trick: after getting the matches with your regex, run a `.+\n*` regex over the Group 2 value:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^:([^:]+):([^:]+)', re.MULTILINE)
s = ":1:text\ntext\n\n:20:text\n\n:21:text\ntext\ntext\n\n:22: \n\n:25:aa\naa\naaaaa"
print([[x.group(1)] + re.findall(r".+\n*", x.group(2)) for x in p.finditer(s)])
```

Here,

- `p.finditer(s)` finds all matches in the string using your regex
- `[x.group(1)]` - a list created from the first group contents
- `re.findall(r".+\n*", x.group(2))` - fetches individual lines from Group 2 contents (with trailing newlines, 0 or more)
- `[] + re.findall` - combining the lists into 1.

Result is

`[['1', 'text\n', 'text\n\n'], ['20', 'text\n\n'], ['21', 'text\n', 'text\n', 'text\n\n'], ['22', ' \n\n'], ['25', 'aa\n', 'aa\n', 'aaaaa']]`

Another approach: match all the substrings with your pattern and then use a `re.sub` to add `), (` between the lines ending with optional newlines:

```
[(x, "({})".format(re.sub(r".+(?!\n*$)\n+", r"\g<0>), (", y))) for x, y in p.findall(s)]
```

Result:

`[('1', '(text\n), (text\n\n)'), ('20', '(text\n\n)'), ('21', '(text\n), (text\n), (text\n\n)'), ('22', '( \n\n)'), ('25', '(aa\n), (aa\n), (aaaaa)')]`

See the [Python 3 demo](https://ideone.com/DPP9mq)

Here:

- `p.findall(s)` - grabs all the matches in the form of a list of tuples containing your capture group contents using your regex
- `(x, "({})".format(re.sub(r".+(?!\n*$)\n+", r"\g<0>), (", y)))` - creates a tuple from Group 1 contents and Group 2 contents that are a bit modified with the `re.sub` the way described below
- `.+(?!\n*$)\n+` - pattern that matches 1+ characters other than newline and then 1+ newline symbols if they are not at the end of the string. If they are at the end of the string, there will be no replacement made (to avoid `, ()` at the end). The `\g<0>` in the replacement string is re-inserting the whole match back into the resulting string and appends `), (` to it.

Comment: Please let know if I missed anything, or anything is unclear.